# cin.clear() doesn't reset cin object

Tags: c++, inputstream, invalid-characters

I have the following loop. It should read numbers until `EndOfFile`, or the user input -999

```
int arr[100];

int index;

for (index = 0; index < 100; index++)
{
 cin >> arr[index];
 if (!cin)
 {
  cin.clear();
  index--;
  continue;
 }
 if (arr[index] == -999)
 {
     break;
 }
}
```

When the user input an invalid thing, such as some `char`s, this loop is being repeated for ever without `clear`ing the error state or stopping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After calling `clear`, you must also somehow remove the invalid input from the stream. Here is one way:

```
 cin >> arr[index];
 if (!cin)
 {
  cin.clear();
  std::string ignoreLine; //read the invalid input into it
  std::getline(cin, ignoreLine); //read the line till next space
  index--;
  continue;
 }
```

It's because when `cin` fails to read the invalid input, it remains there in the stream. It has to be removed, by some means. I just read and ignore it.

You can also use `ignore` as:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),' ');
```

which is better in my opinion provided inputs are *space* separated (and if you don't want to *inspect* the invalid input). The [online doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/) says:

> **istream::ignore**
>
> istream&  ignore( streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF );
>
> **Extract and discard characters**
>
> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them.
>
> The extraction ends when n characters have been extracted and
>   discarded or when the character delim is found, whichever comes first.
>   In the latter case, the delim character itself is also extracted.

Comment: @Mr.DDD: What invalid input your provide?

Comment: Your second version doesn't work. You are igonring `1024` characters or when `' '` is found. However, a user may not input space at the end, and the input will be contiued to 1024 characters!

Comment: @Mr.DDD: You can put some bigger value, instead of `1024`.

Comment: @Mr.DDD: That's good. But what if you've valid input on the same line just after the invalid input?By the way, you could use `std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` instead of `1024`.

Comment: You've to edit your answer, since the space delim won't work until the user input space. User must press ENTER so that \n is found

Comment: @Mr.DDD: I just added `[...] provided inputs are space separated`.