# C++ -While loop keeps on repeating when checking if input is an integer-

Tags: c++, while-loop, modulus

I am trying to do a modulus operation. I ask the user to input two numbers, since modulus only works with integers, I have a while loop that checks if the inputs are integers. Then the while loop ask the user to re-enter the two numbers. But the while loop keeps on repeating and does not allow the user a chance to re-enter the numbers. What will be the proper to go about doing this?

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Modulus (int, int,struct Calculator);

struct Calculator
{
    int per_numb1, per_numb2;
    int per_Result; };

int main () 
{ 
    Calculator Operation1;

    cout << "\nPlease enter the first number to calculate as a modulus: "; 
    cin >> Operation1.per_numb1; 

    cout << "\nPlease enter the second number to calculate modulus: "; 
    cin >> Operation1.per_numb2; 

while ( !( cin >> Operation1.per_numb1)  ||   !( cin >> Operation1.per_numb2))
{ 

        cout << "\nERROR\nInvalid operation \nThe first number or second number   must be an integer"; 
        cout << "\n\nPlease re-enter the first number to begin Modulus: "; 
        cin >> Operation1.per_numb1;  

        cout << "\nPlease re-enter the second number to begin Modulus: ";
        cin >> Operation1.per_numb2;
}





Operation1.per_Result = Modulus(Operation1.per_numb1, Operation1.per_numb2, Operation1); 

cout << "\nThe result  is: " << Operation1.per_Result << endl;

}

int Modulus (int n1, int n2, struct Calculator)
{
    int Answer; 

    Answer = n1 % n2; 

    return Answer; 
}
```

Comment: If the input failed, you need to clear the input stream.

Comment: I tried using cin.clear(Operation1.per_numb1) and cin.clear(Operation1.per_numb2) in the while loop but still doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [infinite loop with cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864540/infinite-loop-with-cin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor to something like this:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <limits>

 using namespace std;

 class Calculator
 {
 public:
     static int Modulus (int n1, int n2);
 };

 int Calculator::Modulus (int n1, int n2)
 {
     return n1 % n2; 
 }

 int getInt(string msg)
 {
     int aa;

     cout << msg;
     cin >> aa;
     while (cin.fail())
     {
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
         cerr <<  "Input was not an integer!" << endl;
         cout << msg;
         cin >> aa;
     } 
     return aa;
 }

 int main () 
 { 
     int num1 = getInt("Enter first value: ");
     int num2 = getInt("Enter second value: ");
     int value = Calculator::Modulus(num1,num2);
     cout << "Answer:" << value << endl ;
 }
```

Comment: I haven't learned about classes yet. What specifics can I just change in the original program that I have for it to function properly?

Comment: Don't use your while loop.  Instead, use a function like the  `getInt()` I provided.  Notice how it checks for the error using `cin.fail()` and how it clears the input stream and the error using `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: Thank You. I used the cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

Answer (score 2):

When the input parsing fails, invalid input data will remain in the stream. You need to

1. clear the stream error state by calling `cin.clear()`.
2. and skip the remaining invalid input.

[See the answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413247/cin-clear-doesnt-reset-cin-object)

Comment: Where exactly will I call cin.clear(). Will it be after I ask the user to re-enter the numbers?

Comment: @user2203675 after you fail to get the number from the user.

Comment: Can you show me an edited copy of my program, so I can see exactly where. I tried what you told me, but it is still not working.