# While loop acting weird in regards to input

Tags: c++, types, while-loop

Been working on a simple school project but I've run into a small problem in regards to validation of user input via the use of a while loop. The following code is used to do so:

```
cout << "How much woud you like to bet?[100, 300, 500]" << endl;
    cin >> int_input;
    if (cin.fail()){
        int_input = 0;
    }

     //Validate check
     while(int_input!=100 && int_input!=300 && int_input!=500){
        cout << "Please enter a valid bet [100, 300, 500]" << endl;
        cin >> int_input;
        if (cin.fail()){
            int_input = 0;
        }
     }
```

The issue arises when a non-integer is entered and the loop ends up spitting out the cout msg over and over again, skipping the request for new input. I assume that a non-integer always returns true for the while loop, but the program should still ask for user input, right?

The cin.fail is a recent addition and might not be necessary as it doesn't solve the problem, although I leave the code as it as it is.

Comment: You need to reset cin. You told it to read an int, gave it bad data, which puts the stream in a bad state where it doesn't block.

Comment: Fwiw, even if you clear, you still need to skip the bad data or you'll be right back where you were.

Comment: Short answer: `cin >>` is bad and you shouldn't use it, especially not for user input. `std::getline` is much better behaved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cin.clear() doesn't reset cin object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413247/cin-clear-doesnt-reset-cin-object)

Comment: Not a perfect dupe, but the target should explain everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an error on the stream, you set your value to `0`. So the loop is run again... and the error's still on the stream. Repeat.

You need to clear the error flag.

```
cin.clear();
```

Then extract enough "bad" data to get to the good part, or you'll just be right back where you started.